# Two Eclipse Projects Include Each Other In Build Path

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I want two Eclipse projects to include each other in their build paths.
[image: The projects on Eo_Nova_Client's build path]

[image: The projects on Eo_Nova_Server's build path]

As you can see, the Client has the Server on it's build path, but not vice versa. When I try to add the client to the server's build path, Eclipse gets angry. How can I accomplish this?

The exception I get is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
GUI cannot be resolved
```

Comment: why do you need circular dependency ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have cyclic project dependencies in eclipse. You should find a way to refactor the code in a way to avoid cylic dependencies. One way can be two move the common files to a third project and add that project to build path of your existing two projects.

Answer (score 2):

A cyclic dependency in eclipse indicates that there is a cycle in the build paths between projects in Eclipse. Because of this cycle, Eclipse does not know which project to compile first.